# Search box on single Post page should only search for posts

Tags: wordpress

I have written code in content-single.php It is searching pages also.I want to search only post when I am Searching from post

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/147222/50884

Answer (score 1):

From what i understand you need to have your WordPress search only search posts for results, you can insert this code before the ‘if(have_posts()):’ line on search.php and it will do that for you.

```
// search only posts    
global $wp_query;    
$args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, array( 'post_type' => 'post' ) );    
query_posts( $args );
```

Further to that you can add any arguments from the standard WP_Query function to there to make the search more custom :)

Comment: I have to modify only for single post